# is there a way to seed a EF Core with code first approach with a IEnumerable/List of objects?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have asp.net core 2.2 project where I am creating the first migration for Entity framework core and I want to read the file image's title and create a list of objects to seed the database with said list of objects, I have a class

which inherits from interface IProductRepository said class contains a List of object Product I have been trying to find if with EF Core 2.2 I would be able to seed a List of products? without using any static method on the overload of OnModelCreating?  or perhaps after creating the first migration?

`public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository`

````
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        Product AddProduct(Product p);
        Product Delete(Guid Id);
        Product UpdateProduct(Product p);
        IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProduct();
        Product GetProduct(Guid id);
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProductBy(ProductType type);
    }```

 

```public List<Product> productsList = new List<Product>();```
````

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.. Have you read through the [built-in seeding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) to see if that'll work for you? I think it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who has the same question I had found a solution a while back injecting the Interface and saving the migration programatically, to avoid conflicts remove any saved migration... and it would work. and dont do manual migrations

```
    {
        public static bool InitializeDB(this AppDbContext context, IProductRepository productRepositoryMock = null, IProductRepository  mock= null)
        {
            var items = productRepositoryMock.GetAllProducts();
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var found = context.Products.Select(x => x.ProductName == item.ProductName).Any();
                if (!found)
                {
                    context.Products.Add(item);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.initialized = 0x01;
            return count > 0;
        }

        public static bool  EnsureDatabaseIsSeeded(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, IProductRepositoryMock mock, IHostingEnvironment env, bool autoMigrateDatabase)
        {
            // seed the database using an extension method
            using (var serviceScope = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices
           .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var ctx= serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
                if (autoMigrateDatabase)
                {
                    ctx.Database.Migrate();
                }
                var res = ctx.InitializeDB(mock);
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
                return res;
            }
        }


    }
```